# Python Linux DNS alias and address reply

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, dns

I've been trying to figure out how to add an alias and IP address with a port as a response to a DNS query with the alias. I am running a simple DNS server written in Python, specifically https://gist.github.com/andreif/6069838

I've read that the alias and IP are normally pulled from the records or zone files but this server doesn't have any so I am unclear as to where they would be added were I to manually specify the alias and IP with a port. I've tried to manually write my DNS response only to realize that I am not sure where the alias and IP are being retrieved from. Also I'm not sure why but when I query the server with nslookup the server seems to also not pass the alias query because the qn variable seems to only hold the string 'server' and nothing else. The qn variable part is in the example below.

```
def dns_response(data):
    request = DNSRecord.parse(data)

    print request

    reply = DNSRecord(DNSHeader(id=request.header.id, qr=1, aa=1, ra=1), q=request.q)

    qname = request.q.qname
    qn = str(qname)
    qtype = request.q.qtype
    qt = QTYPE[qtype]
```

**TL;DR** How do I add an alias and ip address with a port as a reply to an alias DNS query?

**Edit:** I've fixed the simple DNS program for Python 2.7.12, if you have a problem with it not receiving the QName remove the .strip() on the UDP request. Also make sure your domain name ends with '.' as in test.com. otherwise it will not find a match since it will be comparing "test.com" to "test.com.". Also change all of the reply.add_ns with reply.add_answer since the first function does not exist. If you are not receiving an A as a response for your query add reply.add_answer(RR(rname=qname, rtype=1,rclass=1, ttl=TTL, rdata=rdata)) the key change here is the Response type, rtype=1 indicates that it is an A response as opposed to a SOA or NS response. See www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch15 for a detailed brake down of the DNS packet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - a standard DNS `A` or `AAAA` record doesn't contain a port number.

Comment: So if I wanted to add the address without the port, how would I go about doing that?